# Estrutura MVC em servidor remoto

Tags: php, aplicação-web, mvc, servidor, diretório

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de directórios em *localhost*:

```
-config
-hsapp
 |--Controllers
 |--Models
 |--Views
-public
 |--Assets
 |--Index.php
-vendor
composer.json
```

Percebe-se que é uma estrutura MVC. Criei um *virtualhost* direito para a pasta *public*, localmente, e funciona perfeitamente.

Preciso agora de fazer upload para uma pasta em um servidor web, *(dominio.com.br/pasta)* mas não sei como configurar para que, ao entrar na pasta, acesse a pasta *public* de forma que ela seja a pasta raiz, pois o sistema trabalha com rotas.

Alguém pode dar uma luz a um iniciante?

Muito obrigado.

Comment: o servidor é Cpanel?

Comment: Nao. Consegui com a seguinte reescrita:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(?!/public/)(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]

mas agora ele nao encontra a view.

Comment: Não tem relação alguma com MVC. Além disso não está claro o suficiente sobre o que precisa ser feito. Apesar de ser óbvio que o foco do problema é criar uma reescrita de URL ou algo similar. Você mesmo comentou que resolveu mas causa outro problema com as views que acredito que esteja relacionado com o carregamento de CSS e JS (suposição). Ou seja, inviável de fornecer uma solução e tornou-se amplo demais.

Answer (score 1):

Você teria que setar a Raiz do documento como a pasta public, exemplo: [Painel Cpanel](http://prntscr.com/emgb9p)

Assim se o site fosse acessado assim **tmp.dominio.com** ou **dominio.com/tmp** ele na verdade estaria acessando o diretório **public_html/tmp/public**

Comment: Consegui com a seguinte reescrita:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(?!/public/)(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]`